# Can i use query in form builder to get filtered collection in symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

IN the AcmePizza BUndle this is working fine

```
->add('pizza', 'entity', array(
                'class'         => 'Acme\PizzaBundle\Entity\Pizza',
                'query_builder' => function ($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC'); },
            ))
```

Can i do something like that in collection

```
->add('userTasks','collection',array('type' => new UserTaskType(),
                    'class'         => 'acme\myBundle\Entity\UserTask',
                    'query_builder' => function ($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC'); },
                ))
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Using a custom type with `query_builder`? If so, can you paste `UserTaskType`'s code?

Comment: UserTask type has only one field called `name`. I am loading the collection of usertasks on the form. It is working fine. But i only want some filtered tasks like `all tasks where status = 1` not all tasks linked to user

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Your userTasks is an relationship You will find answer for Your case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478583/how-to-orderby-on-onetomany-manytoone). These is just how to sort but if You had required some WHERE conditions it is not so simple but neither it is hard.

I had to filter out some entities, the key to solve it was to create set/get method in entity class returning required set.

In my case it looks like this

```
/**
 * Set values
 *
 * @param ArrayCollection $values
 * @return Attribute
 */
public function setCustomValues($values)
{
    $result = $this->getNotCustomValues();
    foreach ($values as $value)
    {
        $value->setAttribute($this);
        $result->add($value);
    }
    $this->values = $result;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get values
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getCustomValues()
{
    $result = new ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($this->values as $value) {
        if($value->getCustom()) {
            $result->add($value);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And when creating form, name for a field is "customvalues" instead of "values"
So my collection contains only values with custom field true.

Answer (score 1):

You often want to filter collection when you are updating an entity, not having a new one, right?

Here is a working solution, this is an example from controller (CRUD):

```
public function updateAction($id)
{
    $service = $this->getServiceRepository()->loadOne('id', $id);
    $this->checkPermission($service);

    $this->filterInventoryByPrimaryLocation($service);

    if($this->getFormHandler()->process('service_repair_service', $service, array('type' => 'update')))
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->process('persist', $service);

        return $this->render('ServiceRepairBundle:Service:form_message.html.twig', [
            'message' => $this->trans('Service has been updated successfully.')
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('ServiceRepairBundle:Service:form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $this->getFormHandler()->getForm()->createView(),
    ]);
}

private function filterInventoryByPrimaryLocation(Service $service)
{
    $inventory = $service->getInventory();

    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('location', $this->getUser()->getPrimaryLocation()))
        ->orderBy(array('timeInsert' => Criteria::ASC));

    $service->setInventory($inventory->matching($criteria));
}
```

$service = ENTITY,
$inventory = ArrayCollection ( $service->getInventory() )

The key here is to use Doctrine's Criteria, more info here:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

Also think of moving the Criteria in entity itself, make a public method there. When you load it from database, you can fire that method using doctrine's postLoad lifecycle callback. Ofcourse putting it in entity will work, if you don't require any services or things like that.

Another solution would probably be, to move the Criteria in a Form Event inside Form class, if you need filtering only inside a form.

If you need the collection filtering to be done transparently across whole project, write a doctrine listener and put the code inside a postLoad() method. You can also inject dependencies in doctrine listener, but I recommend injecting container itself, because of lazy loading other services, so you do not get circular service references.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I point you to right direction (I hope) :

http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/08/symfony2-ajax-form-republish/

This article deals with field dependencies. for example, when you select a country, you have the towns that belongs to the country that appears in the list.

Answer (score -1):

In Symfony 2.7 i solved this by doing the following in the **UserTaskType**:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserTaskType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('the_name', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'acme\myBundle\Entity\UserTask',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.id > :id')
                        ->setParameter('id', '1')
                        ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
                },
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'acme\myBundle\Entity\UserTask',
        ));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

In your UserTaskType class, add the following method.

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'acme\myBundle\Entity\UserTask',
        'query_builder' => function($repo) {
            return $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC');
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: i tried that nothing is happenning. Do i need to have the repo class for that. i even had error on field name but it still not showing any error for that. Look like that queru builder is not running at all

Comment: Same here. I really really wanted that to work but unfortunately it doesn't for some reason :(

Comment: It doesn't work. First of all you are using a method that doesn't exist (getDefaultOptions). It should be "setDefaultOptions". Anyway, even putting the *query_builder* option in the "setDefaultOptions" method it doesn't work, just because it is not an available option.