# How to OrderBy on OneToMany/ManyToOne

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Product class that has many fields on it for ManyToMany, such as ingredients, sizes, species, etc.. A total of about 14 different fields
Not all of the fields are are relevant to each product.

I have mapping set up like this

```
Class product {
/**
 * @var Species[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Species")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_species",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="speciesId", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "asc"})
 */
private $species;
```

This works great for a manytomany/manyto one.

The problem is in my product_ingredients table I needed to add an additional field, meaning  need to switch from ManyToMany to a OneToMany/ManyToOne
So like this

```
/**
     * @var ProductIngredient[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductIngredient", mappedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $ingredients;
```

Now my ProductIngredient Entity Looks like this

```
 /**
     * @var IngredientType
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IngredientType", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ingredientTypeId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $ingredientType;


    /**
     * @var Ingredient
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ingredient", inversedBy="products", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ingredientId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $ingredient;

    /**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="ingredients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $product;
```

So in my product class for species I use the @ORM\OrderBy so that species is already ordered.. Is there a way I can somehow also do this for my ingredients field?

Or am I doing my logic wrong and these shouldn't even be fields on the product class and should just be looking up by the repository instead?

I was wanting it to be easy so I could loop through my objects like `$product->getIngredients()`
instead of doing

```
$ingredients = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProductIngredient')->findByProduct($product->getId());
```

Answer (score 91):

In the Product entity you just need to add the orderBy to the ingredients relation

```
/**
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"some_attribute" => "ASC", "another_attribute" => "DESC"})
 */
private $ingredients;
```

With PHP 8 attributes:

```
#[ORM\OrderBy(['some_attribute' => 'ASC', 'another_attribute' => 'DESC'])]
private $ingredients;
```

Comment: This throws an error (Unrecognized field: name) because "name" does not exist in ProductIngredient  It is in Ingredient entity.

Comment: Can you give me an example? My product entity connects to ProductIngredient, which connects to Ingredient. I tried doing the orderby in the productingredient class but since it is  a manytoone it is ignored

Comment: You might need to clear the cache after you do this too.  I ran into this issue where it didn't actually apply the order by until after refreshing the cache:

``php console.php orm:clear-cache:metadata && php console.php  orm:clear-cache:query && php console.php orm:clear-cache:result``

Comment: As the names here make sense (`ingredientType` vs `ingredient_type`), I think it could be helpful to rearrange your snippet to comply with the OP's snippet

Comment: Is there a way to order by a joined column? For example if you had a collection of `Car` - each car is related to a `Model`. Would it be possible to use the annotation to order by `model.name` ?

Comment: With php8 atttributes it looks like this: `#[ORM\OrderBy(['sort' => 'ASC'])]`

Answer (score 7):

Well I came up with a hackish way.. Since I really only care about the sort on output, I have made a basic twig extension

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

public function sort(Collection $objects, $name, $property = null)
{
    $values = $objects->getValues();
    usort($values, function ($a, $b) use ($name, $property) {
        $name = 'get' . $name;
        if ($property) {
            $property = 'get' . $property;
            return strcasecmp($a->$name()->$property(), $b->$name()->$property());
        } else {
            return strcasecmp($a->$name(), $b->$name());
        }
    });
    return $values;
}
```

I would like to avoid this hack though and still would like to know a real solution

Comment: Love it, very handy to have something like this in case of those random times you want to order differently

Answer (score 4):

You should use 'query_builder' option in your Form: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder
The value of the option can be something like this:

```
function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')->orderBy('i.name');
}
```

Don't forget to add the "use" statement for EntityRepository

Comment: `@ORM\OrderBy` didn't work for me as my relation is `ManyToOne` this is what I needed!  AND I could also add my `WHERE` clause!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use xml mapping, you could use

```
        <order-by>
            <order-by-field name="some_field" direction="ASC" />
        </order-by>
```

inside your `<one-to-many>` tag.