# Symfony2: sort an ArrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281758/how-to-sort-an-entitys-arraycollection-in-symfony2) one should use OrderBy to sort an ArrayCollection.  Somehow the following does not achieve this result when listing the collection of contact dates for a household:

#### Household entity (snippet)

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Contact", mappedBy="household")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"contact_date" = "DESC"})
 */
private $contacts;
```

#### Contact entity (snippet)

```
    /**
     * Contact
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="contact", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_contact_household_idx", columns={"household_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_contact_type_idx", columns={"contact_type_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_contact_center_idx", columns={"center_id"})})
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Contact
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="contact_date", type="date", nullable=true)
         */
        private $contactDate;
        ...
    }
```

#### Template (for 5 most recent?) (snippet)

```
{% for i in 0..4 %}
{% if household.contacts[i] is defined %}
<tr><td>{{ household.contacts[i].contactDate|date('m/d/Y') }}</td>
...{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Sample result

```
Date    
05/02/2012
05/23/2012
05/30/2012
06/26/2012
06/06/2012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in the field name. As I can see form your **Contact** entity your field is named as `$contactField` but `@ORM\OrderBy({"contact_date" = "DESC"})` from your **Houshold** entity use column name instead of field name. I think that if you change your `contact_date` to `contactDate` it will be working.

It is very strange that you have no error from Doctrine about this issue. Because Doctrine usually operate with fields but not columns.

Comment: `OrderBy` is an exception, it accepts a table field names, not a property name.

Comment: @meze: I had thought so, too.  Turns out this was (part of) the answer.  To find this, though, I had to delete the Doctrine XML metadata, which was masking some other minor annotation mapping errors.